# How to filter a dataset in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to filter a dataset in javascript?,

my dataset:

```
 [1, "AGENT001", "John", "bdev1@example.com, "Sales", 1, false, true]
 [2, "AGENT002", "Susan", "bdev2@example.com", "Sales", 1, true, true]
```

how to filter by the 6th column = true?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and instance).

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+filter+nested+arrays+by+value) of [Filter Array of Array for values inside nested array](/q/55972563/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check whether the item at index `6` is `true`:

```js
const items = [
  [1, "AGENT001", "John", "bdev1@example.com", "Sales", 1, false, true],
  [2, "AGENT002", "Susan", "bdev2@example.com", "Sales", 1, true, true]
];
const filtered = items.filter(e => e[6]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Do they have to be constants?

Comment: @MadelineKallis not at all, no.